# 2 separate independent plots in the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data like this:

```
mydata(
var0 = 4,4,4,4.5,4.5,4.6,4.8,5.5,5.7,7,7.5,7.6,8,8.5,8.6,9,9,9.5,9.6,10
var1 = 10,9.6,9.5,9.3,8,8.5,8.3,7.5,7,7,6.8,6.7,6.3,6,5.5,5.3,4.8,4.5,4.3,4
con0 = 0,5,10,15,50,80,100,150,180,200,220,250,300,350,400,450,480,500,550,600
con1= 600,580,550,530,480,460,450,350,330,300,200,170,165,120,75,65,25,15,10,0
)
```

I want con0 and con1 in the y-axis and its corresponding values var0 and var1 in the x axis. Is there a way to plot 2 separate independent plots in the same graph. I tried to do it with the following code using just con0 but the problem is if I switch to con1 the shape changes. Any suggestions?

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(y = con0)) + 
geom_line(aes(x = var0, colour = "ascent")) +   
geom_line(aes(x = var1, colour = "descent"))
```

Comment: Please double check the data creation code for `mydata` (use the "edit" button for corrections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
library(ggplot)
df <- data.frame(
  var0 = c(4,4,4,4.5,4.5,4.6,4.8,5.5,5.7,7,7.5,7.6,8,8.5,8.6,9,9,9.5,9.6, 10),
  var1 = c(10,9.6,9.5,9.3,8,8.5,8.3,7.5,7,7,6.8,6.7,6.3,6,5.5,5.3,4.8,4.5,4.3,4),
  con0 = c(0,5,10,15,50,80,100,150,180,200,220,250,300,350,400,450,480,500,550,600),
  con1= c(600,580,550,530,480,460,450,350,330,300,200,170,165,120,75,65,25,15,10,0)
)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = var0, y = con0), color = 'red') + 
  geom_line(aes(x = var1, y = con1), color = 'blue')
```